# How to fix "The non-nullable variable '_db' must be initialized. Try adding an initializer expression"

Tags: database, flutter, null, initialization, sqflite

"The non-nullable variable '_db' must be initialized. Try adding an initializer expression"
Could anyone help me with this *non-nullable* error?
I am using flutter to make an android app and while using the 'sqflite' and making a database, this error pops up I don't know how to really fix this
Here is my Code below,
I am using the last version of **Flutter** & **Dart**,

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:newtodoapp/taskmodel.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

class DatabaseHelper {
  static final DatabaseHelper instance = DatabaseHelper._instance();
  static Database _db;


  DatabaseHelper._instance();


  String tasksTable = 'task_table';
  String colId = 'id';
  String colTitle = 'title';
  String colDate = 'date';
  String colPriority = 'priority';
  String colStatus = 'status';

  // Task Tables
  // Id | Title | Date | Priority | Status
  // 0     ''      ''      ''         0
  // 2     ''      ''      ''         0
  // 3     ''      ''      ''         0

  Future<Database> get db async {
    if (_db == null) {
    _db = await _initDb();
   }
   return _db;
  }
  Future<Database> _initDb() async {
    Directory dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = dir.path + '/todo_list.db';
    final todoListDb =
    await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _createDb);
    return todoListDb;
  }

  void _createDb(Database db, int version) async {
   await db.execute(
  'CREATE TABLE $tasksTable($colId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,'
      ' $colTitle TEXT, $colDate TEXT, $colPriority TEXT, $colStatus INTEGER)',
    );
  }

  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getTaskMapList() async {
    Database db = await this.db;
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> result = await db.query(tasksTable);
   return result;
  }

  Future<List<Task>> getTaskList() async {
   final List<Map<String, dynamic>> taskMapList = await getTaskMapList();
   final List<Task> taskList = [];
   taskMapList.forEach((taskMap) {
   taskList.add(Task.fromMap(taskMap));
  });
  taskList.sort((taskA, taskB) => taskA.date.compareTo(taskB.date));
  return taskList;
   }

   Future<int> insertTask(Task task) async {
   Database db = await this.db;
   final int result = await db.insert(tasksTable, task.toMap());
   return result;
 }

 Future<int> updateTask(Task task) async {
   Database db = await this.db;
   final int result = await db.update(
   tasksTable,
   task.toMap(),
   where: '$colId = ?',
   whereArgs: [task.id],
   );
   return result;
  }

  Future<int> deleteTask(int id) async {
   Database db = await this.db;
   final int result = await db.delete(
   tasksTable,
   where: '$colId = ?',
   whereArgs: [id],
   );
  return result;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

declare your variable like this.

static Database? _db;

Comment: Tnx to your response, it really works. Morover, I have to add    ?near Database and ! near _db,   the question that I don't understand is Why?!!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @ArShiaJs Well dart is now null safe and it will not allow the possibility of anything to be null so you will have to tell the compiler that you will make sure yourself that it is not null. If you use old version of dart(do not know the exact version) your older code will word just fine. But null safety is good thing and it makes you aware of nullable types

Comment: @HarshKumar I got it, thanks very much for your great response